# SQL Server 2008 (x64) and DSN-less Connectionn (Error: Data source name not found and no default driver specified )

Tags: sql-server-2008

I yanked all DSNs on a test machine in favor of a ConnectionString that specified a server by name. Now I'm getting

> "Data source name not found and no default driver specified".

My development machine is Windows 7 (x64) with VS2010 and a separate SQL Server (x64).

Any ideas on what driver I should be using? Apparently, system.data.odbc is wrong for ASP.Net (x64).

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="AppODBC"
         connectionString="Server=XXXXXXXX;
         uid=YYYYYYYY;
         pwd=ZZZZZZZZ;
         trusted_connection=No;
         wsid=BCDEV1;
         database=MasterTraq_Dev"
         providerName="System.Data.Odbc"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Data Source Name not found" means that it can't find the ODBC Entry.  No default driver specified means that the conneciton string is missing information about which driver to use.

The connection string probably just needs to be tweaked. Can you post the connection string (with any sensitive data removed or obfuscated)?

You can use ODBC.NET with asp.net x64 as long as the drivers are installed and the connection string is correct.  However, with SQL Server the recommendation is to use System.Data.SqlClient, which is optimized for SQL Server.

Regardless, you can likely find a suitable connection string here: http://www.carlprothman.net/Technology/ConnectionStrings/ODBCDSNLess/tabid/90/Default.aspx

Comment: Thanks David. The connection string has been added. I will follow the article link.

Comment: Better!  You're specifically missing the "Driver={SQL Native Client};" portion, and you should also remove the wsid portion and replace it with  "Server=*ServerName*"

Comment: Thanks David. I added `Driver={SQL Native Client}`, and removed `providerName="System.Data.Odbc`. All is well in my little world now. Thank you.